# Flutter Stripe Payment Error Publishable Key is required / missing

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I have created a test demo for stripe payment but when I test by clicking on the button. I get an [image: error]

The API key is required but i had already given that. Please help me in finding out the error. Most probabily its my way of calling the key from main function

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_stripe/flutter_stripe.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> main() async {
  Stripe.publishableKey =
  "pk_test_51JT7jkCTAUDjRNFVfafy4Gskx1KzUNk8nPj8T51zzCPE18fA17DOFO6MqSZVTCxhVCSWGwouDSe0yjcObAznHLW600VBoGyDcg";
  await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
  runApp(const PaymentScreen());
}

class PaymentScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const PaymentScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Stripe Payment',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
      ),
      home: const PaymentPage(),
    );
  }
}

class PaymentPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const PaymentPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Future<void> initPaymentSheet(context, {required String email, required int amount}) async {
      try {
        // 1. create payment intent on the server
        final response = await http.post(
            Uri.parse(
                'https://us-central1-stripe-checkout-flutter.cloudfunctions.net/stripePaymentIntentRequest'),
            body: {
              'email': email,
              'amount': amount.toString(),
            });

        final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
        log(jsonResponse.toString());

        //2. initialize the payment sheet
        await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
          paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
            paymentIntentClientSecret: jsonResponse['paymentIntent'],
            merchantDisplayName: 'Flutter Stripe Store Demo',
            customerId: jsonResponse['customer'],
            customerEphemeralKeySecret: jsonResponse['ephemeralKey'],
            style: ThemeMode.light,
            testEnv: true,
            merchantCountryCode: 'SG',
          ),
        );

        await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();

        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(content: Text('Payment completed!')),
        );
      } catch (e) {
        if (e is StripeException) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text('Error from Stripe: ${e.error.localizedMessage}'),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text('Error: $e')),
          );
        }
      }
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Stripe Demo App"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                await initPaymentSheet(context, email: "example@gmail.com", amount: 200000);
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Buy Token 2000 USD',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can test the code. It has no errors other than that

Answer (score 0):

While I'd generally suggest you file this as an [issue](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues) with the `flutter_stripe` repo, you can consider whether you might be missing a line from your initialization, compared to their [example](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe#example):

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // <- you don't have this line

  // set the publishable key for Stripe - this is mandatory
  Stripe.publishableKey = stripePublishableKey;
  runApp(PaymentScreen());
}
```

Comment: It still shows me the same error. This is not the issue. I have tried that too :(

Answer (score 0):

Payment was not able to suceed similar issue I was facing with Stripe:
So I had added merchantID, and urlScreme to it before initializing the flutter instance. It will verify same merchant

```
Stripe.publishableKey = "pk_test_RS3cXiyeMHhEmpqnojBPuukSZQdjA7S00GE5LjhtqLongSecureKey342423";
Stripe.merchantIdentifier = "acct_1IL78e48329489014f";

Stripe.stripeAccountId = "acct_1IL78e48329489014f";
Stripe.urlScheme = "flutterstripe";
await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
```